# Get the class or struct that conforms to a protocol for use in function using Generics

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

My question if you have an `Array` of objects that conforms to a `protocol`. I want to iterate over the array calling a method on each member in the array. However the method I want to call is static and uses generics. I need to get the class of the element in the array to do this. how do you get the class of that object? Is it possible?

I am writing a library of generic functions in Swift.

I have a protocol called `DBAble` which has as function:

```
static func get<T: DBable >(id:Int) -> T?
```

I have an array of objects that conform to DBAble:

```
let objs:[DBAble] = []
```

I want to iterate over the array and call:

```
for obj in objs {
    obj.get(id: anInt)
}
```

however I am getting this message:

> Static member 'get' cannot be used on instance of type 'DBable.Protocol'

Is there a way of finding the class (or type of struct) of the object that conforms to the protocol? I understand that I can do:

```
if obj is User {

}
```

however this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Your edit hasn't clarified what you expect `get(_:)` to return when called in your for loop. Do you expect `T == obj.dynamicType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the application approach it that the type T in the bellow method

```
 static func get<T: DBable >(id:Int) -> T?
```

has to be known at compile time, whereas the the dynamicType will give you the type at run time.

For anyone else considering this question the answer is no it is not possible to find the type for use in a generic function at runtime. As explained in the comments by @hamish

```
  "element.dynamicType is the actual type of a given element in your array. Your get(_:) method has a generic parameter T that must be known at compile time"
```